# Python inotify - Execute function upon new file creation

Tags: python, inotify

In a python script I am watching a directory for new files coming from a scanner. Currently my code is only reacting on the IN_CLOSE_WRITE event. I am aware that the right way would be to watch out for a IN_CREATE event followed by a IN_CLOSE_WRITE event.

My current code looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
import logging
import inotify.adapters
import ocrmypdf

def DoOCR(filePath, fileName):
    print("Processing {}".format(fileName))
    try:
       fullPath = os.path.join(filePath, fileName)
       ocrmypdf.ocr(fullPath, fullPath, deskew=True, clean=True, language="deu")
    except ocrmypdf.exceptions.PriorOcrFoundError as err:
       print("Already processed: {0}".format(err))
    except:
       print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
       raise

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Setup logging.
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    #logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    i = inotify.adapters.Inotify()

    pathToWatch = '/srv/smb/scanneddocs'
    if not os.path.exists(pathToWatch):
        os.mkdir(pathToWatch)

    watchMask = inotify.constants.IN_CREATE | inotify.constants.IN_CLOSE_WRITE

    i.add_watch(pathToWatch, watchMask)
    
    for event in i.event_gen(yield_nones=False):
        (_, type_names, path, filename) = event

        #TODO: Check that a IN_CREATE is followed by a IN_CLOSE_WRITE
        if "IN_CLOSE_WRITE" in type_names:
            print("PATH=[{}] FILENAME=[{}] EVENT_TYPES={}".format(path, filename, type_names))
            name, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
            print(extension)
            if extension.lower() == ".pdf":
                DoOCR(pathToWatch, filename)
            else:
                print("{} is no PDF file. Skipping...".format(filename))
```

What would be the best way to ensure that both events occurred after each other?

Comment: Why do you need to check for `IN_CREATE`? Could the scanner also overwrite an existing file, and you don't want to detect that?

Comment: Anyway, you could add a detector for `IN_CREATE`, and put the filename in a set. Then when you get `IN_CLOSE_WRITE`, check that the filename is in the set.

Comment: @Barmar If I only checked IN_CLOSE_WRITE modifying a document in that particular directory would also trigger the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the created files to a `set`, then check the set when you get the `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` event.

```
    created_files = set()
    for event in i.event_gen(yield_nones=False):
        (_, type_names, path, filename) = event

        if "IN_CREATE" in type_names:
            created_files.add(filename)
        if "IN_CLOSE_WRITE" in type_names:
            if filename not in created_files:
                continue
            created_files.remove(filename) # remove unneeded item
            print("PATH=[{}] FILENAME=[{}] EVENT_TYPES={}".format(path, filename, type_names))
            name, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
            print(extension)
            if extension.lower() == ".pdf":
                DoOCR(pathToWatch, filename)
            else:
                print("{} is no PDF file. Skipping...".format(filename))
```

Comment: Your idea is very similar to one I've already tried. The problem here is that as long as I watch the directory the for loop is never left.

Comment: You can use a timeout to exit the loop if there are no events for a period of time.

Comment: `for event in i.event_gen(yield_nones=False, timeout_s=1):`

Comment: What I want to accomplish is that the directory is constantly being watched. So some kind of loop will be necessary. But maybe the whole for loop construct is completely the wrong way...

Comment: If you want to watch it constantly, why is it a problem that the loop is never left? Maybe you can use multi-threading so this doesn't block the rest of the application.

Comment: Obviously I did not get the point in the first place. The set should solve all my problems. I probably just need to make sure that old entries are removed in order not to waste memory over time...

Comment: My code does that -- see `created_files.remove(filename)`